# Stored Procedure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there something like Stored Procedure in MongoDB ? 
Please don't specify db.eval since it is deprecated from version 3.0 onward .
Couldn't find anything in document other that db.eval

Answer (score 7):

There is [system.js](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/), but apart from that, there's nothing. And even that method is discouraged by mongodb authors.

> Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB. Application code also is typically most effective when it shares version control with the application itself.

Comment: So what if driver logic become more complex than executing on database? `Do not use Mongo then`?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: not sure what you mean there

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have a complex logic that is working ~5 times slower if running via C# mongo driver comparing to in-database execution. So absence of support for a `system.js` in new driver is the blocker for this issue.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: well yes, don't use mongodb then :)