# Mongodb: server side operation on documents

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I need to filter and aggregate documents from **collection "A"** and put the result in a **collection "B"**. I would like to perform all the operations server side because I don't need those data on the client, so I searched for some sort of stored procedure for Mongodb. Perhaps I could use stored javascript but according to some posts [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846122/stored-procedure-in-mongodb) it is greatly discouraged.

I there another way besides stored javascript and client side query and insert ?

Comment: You can use aggregation stages and operations to perform all operations within the aggregation query (all these happen on the MongoDB server) _and_ write the resulting documents to another collection. See the aggregation's `$marge` and the `$out` stages which allow writing to other collection.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation's $marge and the $out, as suggested by prasad_'s comment, are the solution for server side computation. It turned out that my knowledge of the data was poor and the documents are so few that any performance consideration is irrelevant.They can be easily loaded client side and then inserted into a new collection.